# Is it possible to write JUnit tests that are agnostic to your JAX-RS implementation?

Tags: rest, junit, jax-rs

I wrote a REST web service using JAX-RS that knows nothing about the specific JAX-RS implementation I chose. I happen to be using TomEE which means my JAX-RS implementation is ApacheCXF.

I'd like to write unit tests for the web service that also know nothing about the JAX-RS implementation. Is this possible? So far every example I've found involves using classes from a specific JAX-RS implementation (JAXRSClientFactory for ApacheCXF, Jersey Test Framework, etc).

I've started experimenting with tomee-embedded and am able to test my EJB's but it doesn't seem to startup the REST services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use Arquillian paired with an Embedded TomEE. Arquillian provides a ton of functionality but I'm only using it to start/stop the Embedded TomEE. Therefore, all I needed to do was add this to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>${tomee.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I could write a JUnit test with a little extra Arquillian stuff and plain JAX-RS:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyServiceIT {

    @ArquillianResource
    private URL webappUrl;

    @Deployment()
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(MyService.class)
            .addAsWebInfResource("META-INF/persistence.xml") //Refers to src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-resources.xml", "resources.xml") //Refers to src/test/resources/test-resources.xml
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void randomTest() throws URISyntaxException {
        //Get data from the web service.
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(webappUrl.toURI().resolve("myentity"));
        Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        int status = response.getStatus();
        List<MyEntity> myEntities = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<MyEntity>>() {});

        //Perform some tests on the data
    }
}
```